# Visual studio 2010 resizing winforms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I develop in a laptop that has a resolution of 1280x800. In my winforms app there are some forms that their height is bigger than 800. Normally I connect a lcd 17" or 19", but when not and I open a form that has 1280x1024, visual studio 2010 automatically resizes to my laptop resolution my form and then I have some troubles to resize all the controls.

I wonder if there is an option to avoid this behavior.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6651115/250725.  Seems to suggest this is designed behavior since the size of the Form cannot exceed the display.  There are some work-arounds to dealing with this situation, but don't directly deal with your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it's the same problem, later I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You have study about the [.DockStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle.aspx) and [.AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize.aspx) behavior