# Prevent re-sizing windows form depend upon the resolution

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on Windows form application. After deploying the application I am getting screens with different sizes in laptop and desktop. This makes some of my menus to disappear and reports to be not shown properly. Do we have a solution for this?

While changing the resolution of my system my form size also getting changing. I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your app with lowest possible resolution (Like: 800x600) and then
Use **Panels** and when you add your tools into those panels **dock** them, that might be helpfull, that's what I am using in all my applications and it is going with screen resolution all the time.

Comment: i am using group box in all my forms,,but i am getting this issue

Comment: how i can give resolution to my application

Comment: You're not giving a resolution, you will give a custom size of form. And also set `WindowsState` to be `Maximized`

Comment: sir,,i already put my all form windowsstate to be Maximized and all form i used one group box ,,then am adding tools to inside the Group box,,is it oke?

Comment: This post might be usefull for you: [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6651523/1882535)

Answer (score 1):

I put this section of code in my Load event method:

```
this.MaximumSize = this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
```

When a user attempts to double click on the top of the form to maximise it, it stays in the same size. Therefore, maximising the form in this case is disabled.

Comment: i think this problem is resolution problem..different system am getting different form size

Answer (score 1):

Make it small enough to fit in the screen having the smallest resolution. And make your forms `WindowState` as normal. Then you'll see that it fits all the screens. But if you want `Maximized` state on all screens then you should first apply my first sentence, with @Nidzaaaa's answer.