# Is there any way to set the height of winform more than 1044?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to set form height to 2000 but it return height size to 1044 in C# winform.
Is any way to make height size more than 1044 in winform C#?

Comment: what's the value of form's `MaxHeight` property?

Comment: How are you setting the height?

Comment: How tall is your screen?

Comment: What happens if you change resolution, either smaller or larger?

Comment: ClickRick, I'd imagine absolutely nothing different. OP - How are you setting the height? programatically? designer? if the former, show your code. if the latter, does the designer window display the changes?

Comment: @Sayse My screen is 1080 tall, and Designer restricts a form to 1100. Alternatively, if I run any program (e.g. Notepad), and move the window towards the bottom of the screen, I can then resize it vertically but again limited to 1100.

Comment: @user3713495 I wonder why you have to set the form's height to more than your monitor's display height. It's not going to be user friendly.

Comment: As it turns out - This question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6651115/1324033).... But then I don't understand why you'd ever want to design a form that has a height greater than the majority of monitor resolutions

Comment: @user3713495 The question about what you're trying to achieve is a good one. There might be other solutions to your underlying problem so you'd have to explain your reason for wanting to do this, probably as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is basically no, though [Is the size of a Form in Visual Studio designer limited to screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651115/is-the-size-of-a-form-in-visual-studio-designer-limited-to-screen-resolution) has a workaround for some situations.

As explained in that Q&A, this is intentional and by design:

> From the [MSDN](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/350887/windows-form-clipped-at-run-time-to-screen-resolution)
>
> > Property Form.Size: 
> >     The maximum value of this property is limited by
> >     the resolution of the screen on which the form runs. The value cannot
> >     be greater than 12 pixels over each screen dimension (horizontal + 12
> >     and vertical + 12).